# I get "InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined." when I log out whilst on my admin route that is restricted to admins only

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand why am I getting that error but what I do know is this:

- It only happens when I log out whilst on my admin route `/admin`.
- I don't have a login route and I'm not sure where and why have I used
  that undefined login route.
- If I move out the admin middleware group along with the `/admin`
  route from `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){}` to
  `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){}` it fixes the
  problem.
- I searched for "login" in my entire project but didn't find anything
  route related.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this problem.

Here's some of my code that involves the admin route:

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

    Route::get('/signup', 'PagesController@signup')->name('signUpView');
    Route::get('/signin', 'PagesController@signin')->name('signInView');
    Route::post('/signup', 'UsersController@signUp')->name('signup');
    Route::post('/signin', 'UsersController@signIn')->name('signin');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){

        Route::get('/logout', 'UsersController@logOut')->name('logout');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'roles', 'roles' => 'admin'], function(){
            Route::get('/admin', 'pagesController@admin')->name('admin');
        });

    });

});
```

Middleware I have used for roles:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() === null){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
        if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles ) {
                return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

Log out function:

```
public function logOut(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Admin view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="wrapper">
    <form class='uploadForm' action="{{ route('createTag') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="tagName">Tag Name</label>
        <input class='input' type="text" name="tagName" placeholder="Tag Name">
        <input type="file" name="tagImage"> {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button class='Submit' type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that you get that error !

**Why ?**

because of the auth middleware, when you log out there is a redirect back to the where you, **but** the last location (admin) requires that you log in to continue, that's why the middleware redirect you to the loggin page assuming that you have one and it's related named route `login`.

For more information take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart) :

Redirecting Unauthenticated Users

> When the auth middleware detects an unauthorized user, it will either
>   return a JSON 401 response, or, if the request was not an AJAX
>   request, redirect the user to the login named route.
>
> You may modify this behavior by defining an `unauthenticated` function
>   in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
>
> protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
> {
>     return $request->expectsJson()
>                 ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
>                 : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
> }
> ```

Comment: So I just move out the middleware with roles out of the 'auth' middleware? Also I assume somewhere in the project files, the default login route name is set to login by Laravel? Can I change it to my differently named sign in route?

Comment: I updated the answer where you can modify the name of the route change `guest(route('login'));` to `guest(route('signInView'));` and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect to route that doesn't needs authorization, i.e.

```
public function logOut(){
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('signInView');
}
```